# Printing `argv[]` with nasm

Tags: nasm

I'm trying to print the command line arguments given to my program, using nasm:

```
GLOBAL main
EXTERN printf

section .rodata
fmt db "Argument: %s", 10, 0

section .text
main:
    push    ebp                 ; push ebp0
    mov     ebp, esp        ; [ebp1] == ebp0

    push    dword[ebp+8]        ; push argc
    call    print_args

    mov     eax, 0      ; return(0)
    mov     esp, ebp    ; pop
    pop     ebp             ; stack frame
    ret

print_args:
    push    ebp             ; pusheo ebp1
    mov     ebp, esp    ; [ebp2] == ebp1
    mov     edi, dword[ebp+8]   ; [ebp+8] == argc
    jmp     lop
postlop:
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret


lop:
    sub     edi, 1
    cmp     edi, 0
    jz      postlop
    mov     esi, [ebp] ; [esi] == ebp1
    mov     ebx, [esi + 12] ; [esi+12] = [ebp1+12] = argv[0]?
    push    ebx
    push    fmt
    call    printf
    jmp     lop
```

However, this prints only garbage (I believe this should print `argv[0]`, `argc-1` times.).

I'm compiling my code with:

```
nasm -f elf32 main.asm
gcc -m32 main.o -o main.out
```

What is wrong?

*By the way, using* `dword[ebp+8]` *works correctly to pick up* `argc`.

I'm running this on ubuntu. Program does output `Argument: ...` `argc-1` times, but the `...` is garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like `[epb+8]`is `argc`, `[esi + 12]` is `argv`, *i.e.* the address of *the array of* argument adresses.  Thus, in order to find `argv[0]`, you have to dereference once more.

```
mov     esi, [ebp]      ; [esi] == ebp1
mov     ebx, [esi + 12] ; [esi+12] = [ebp1+12] = argv
push    dword [ebx]     ; [ebx] = argv[0]
       ;^^^^^^^^^^^
push    fmt
call    printf
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this and this is all you need

Assemble as so. On my 32-bit debian 9 VM:

```
$ nasm -felf32 -g args.s -o args.o
$ gcc -no-pie args.o -o args


        segment .data
format  db      "%s",0x0a,0
        segment .text
        global  main            ; let the linker know about main
        extern  printf          ; resolve printf from libc
main:
        push    ebp             ; prepare stack frame for main
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 8
        mov     edi, dword[ebp+8]    ; get argc into edi
        mov     esi, dword[ebp+12]   ; get first argv string into esi
start_loop:
        xor     eax, eax
        push    dword [esi]     ; must dereference esi; points to argv
        push    format
        call    printf
        add     esi, 4          ; advance to the next pointer in argv
        dec     edi             ; decrement edi from argc to 0
        cmp     edi, 0          ; when it hits 0, we're done
        jnz     start_loop      ; end with NULL pointer
end_loop:
        xor     eax, eax
        leave
        ret
```

Comment: Hi. I'm new to x86 assembly. Any reason why you're doing `sub esp, 8` ? That's allocating the equivalent of 2 4-byte ints on the stack but they're not being used.